# How do I add a php extension to php.ini file?

Tags: php.ini

I need to add a php extension to a custom php.ini file. The extension is installed locally, not in usr/lib. How do I make php "look for" the extension there?

Comment: Specify it as an absolute path?

Comment: Nope, didn't work.

Comment: You should be able to override the `extension_dir` setting with the custom php.ini to point it at the directory which contains the extension.

Comment: I'll keep trying then. Must be some setting.